# Expansion of prime zeta function near singularities

Tags: prime-numbers, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, zeta-functions, singularity

The [prime zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html) has the following expansion near its singularity at 1:

$$P(1+\varepsilon) = -\ln \varepsilon + C + O(\varepsilon)$$

It also has a singularity at the reciprocal of every [square-free positive integer](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squarefree.html). What is its expansion near each of these singularities? Is it

$$P(1/n+\varepsilon) = -\frac{\mu(n)}{n} \ln \varepsilon + C + O(\varepsilon) $$

where $\mu$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main ingredients here. The first is $\zeta$ near its singularity $s=1$:

$$ \zeta(1+\varepsilon)=\frac{1}{\varepsilon}+\gamma+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon) $$

(where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant). The other is the Mobius inversion formula:

$$ P(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(k)}{k}\ln \zeta(ks). $$

This is mentioned on the MathWorld page you linked for the prime zeta function $P(s)$. Notice the only nonzero terms occur when $k$ is squarefree. Setting $s=1/n+\epsilon$ yields

$$ P(1/n+\epsilon)=\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\ln\zeta(1+n\varepsilon)+\sum_{\substack{k=1\\ k\ne n}}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(k)}{k}\ln\zeta(k(1/n+\varepsilon)). $$

Letting $\varepsilon\to0$ in this case, and using the $\mathcal{O}$ expansion of $\zeta$ and $\ln$ yields

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \ln\zeta(1+n\varepsilon) & =\ln\left(\frac{1}{n\varepsilon}+\gamma+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon)\right) \\ & = -\ln(n\epsilon)+\ln(1+n\gamma\epsilon+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)) \\ & = -\ln(n\varepsilon)+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon). \end{array} $$

Therefore,

$$ P(1/n+\varepsilon)=-\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\ln(\varepsilon)+\left[-\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\ln(n)+\sum_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne n}}^\infty \frac{\mu(k)}{k}\ln\zeta(k/n)\right]+\mathcal{O}(\varepsilon). $$

Comment: Your methods works the same way for the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ : around $s=\rho/n$ or $1/n$, assuming the RH,
$P(s) - \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log\zeta(ns)$ is analytic thus $P(s) - \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (s-\rho/n),P(s) + \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log (s-1/n)$ is analytic. Due to the infinitely many non-trivial zeros, those $\log$ singularities accumulate to the right of $\Re(s)=0$ which is $P(s)$'s natural boundary

Comment: Thank you. If one subtracts these logarithmic singularities from the prime zeta function as in https://imgur.com/a/KqHbxWM, it seems like it should be possible to extend the real part of the result to $s < 0$ in a smooth, natural way. Is this possible?

Comment: More generally I wonder whether it is possible to extend a complex function past a natural boundary by subtracting the singularities on that boundary, performing analytic (?) continuation, and re-adding the singularities.

Comment: Can you really subtract a logarithmic function for every singularity though? The singularities may be a discrete set on Re(s)>0, but I suspect every pure imaginary is a limit point of the singularities (including the ones from the nontrivial zeros of $\zeta$ which @reuns mentions), which I feel will be a serious obstruction.

Comment: That's why I said $\Re(s)=0$ is a natural boundary : $P(s)$ isn't analytic anywhere there  $\implies$ no possible analytic continuation beyond

Comment: $\log s$ doesn't have any natural boundary

Comment: @reuns Well, $1/(s-\alpha)^2$ is even better behaved than $\log(s-\alpha)$ near $s=\alpha$, requiring no branch cut, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/(s-1/n)^2$ won't converge for any $s$, and $\{1/n\}$ only has one limit point, let alone an entire axis of them, so I am skeptical of the OP's idea of removing the logarithmic singularities at the natural boundary of $P(s)$ by simply subtracting logarithms.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean. Branch cuts and natural boundaries aren't the same at all. If $f$ has a natural boundary at $\Re(s)=0$ then $f(s)+\log (s-a)$ has a natural boundary at $\Re(s)=0$. The derivative of $\log(s)$ is $1/s$ which is analytic : branch cuts move when continuing analytically the function, they are not boundaries.

Comment: @reuns I don't understand your point. I know branch cuts are not natural boundaries. While I do feel like branch cuts might be an extra complication with OP's idea, I was saying that even disregarding branch cuts I don't think OP's idea will work. To reiterate my understanding of OP's idea:

Comment: As inspiration, one may "remove" poles from functions by subtracting rational functions with the same poles and residues, which by partial fractions is the same as subtracting $1/(z-\alpha)^m$s. One could even subtract an infinite number of such powers to get an entire function. OP's idea, I think, is to subtract logarithmic functions from $P(s)$ to "remove" all of its singularities, yielding a well-defined function that continues left of ${\rm Re}(s)=0$. But I don't think we can even add up all these logarithmic functions, since their singularities have an entire axis of limit points.